# What are the Google Slide background dimensions?

Tags: presentation-design

I need to resize an image to use as a background in Google Slides. I need to know the height to width ratio so that I can make the appropriate adjustments.

I have already taken a look at this Q&A:
[Stack Exchange: What are the pixel dimensions of a presentation slide for Open Office/Libre Office Impress?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/whats-the-pixel-dimensions-of-a-presentation-slide-for-open-office-libre-offi)

Comment: [You can change the size of the slides](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3447672?hl=en) so the answer is—it depends on the size your slides are set to.

Answer (score 4):

Per Cai's comment here is the link to Google's help page:

[Change the size of your slides - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3447672?hl=en)

Once the ratio is known just trim your images to match.

Answer (score 0):

The page layout ratios don't appear to be accurate in Google Slides. If you follow the rations the slides won't fit. I ended up inserting a PSD canvas that was 800W 448H and it fit about perfect for a Widescreen Layout.